# Secondary DNS is not up to date

Tags: domain-name-system, freebsd

I have a primary DNS on my FreeBSD server ns0.dddddd.eu and secondary DNS on Xname.org.

But secondary DNS's on Xname.org are not up to date! Commands """#dig @ns0.xname.org dddddd.eu mx"""" and ""#dig @ns0.dddddd.eu dddddd.eu mx"""" return different answers! **NS-servers servers do not see my MX-record mail2.dddddd.eu**. Why? Please help me!

**#dig @ns0.xname.org dddddd.eu mx**

```
###############################################################################################
 #dig @ns0.dddddd.eu dddddd.eu mx

; <<>> DiG 9.6.2-P2 <<>> @ns0.dddddd.eu dddddd.eu mx
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 10626
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 3

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;dddddd.eu.            IN    MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
dddddd.eu.        3600    IN    MX    10 mail.dddddd.eu.
dddddd.eu.        3600    IN    MX    20 mail2.dddddd.eu.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
dddddd.eu.        3600    IN    NS    ns0.dddddd.eu.
dddddd.eu.        3600    IN    NS    ns1.xname.org.
dddddd.eu.        3600    IN    NS    ns0.xname.org.
dddddd.eu.        3600    IN    NS    ns2.xname.org.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
mail.dddddd.eu.    3600    IN    A    11.111.111.111
mail2.dddddd.eu.    3600    IN    A    22.222.222.222
ns0.dddddd.eu.        3600    IN    A    11.111.111.111

################################################################################################

#dig @ns0.xname.org dddddd.eu mx

; <<>> DiG 9.6.2-P2 <<>> @ns0.xname.org dddddd.eu mx
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 63585
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 3, ADDITIONAL: 4
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;dddddd.eu.            IN    MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
dddddd.eu.        3600    IN    MX    10 mail.dddddd.eu.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
dddddd.eu.        3600    IN    NS    ns1.xname.org.
dddddd.eu.        3600    IN    NS    ns0.xname.org.
dddddd.eu.        3600    IN    NS    ns0.dddddd.eu.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
mail.dddddd.eu.    3600    IN    A    11.111.111.11
ns0.xname.org.        600    IN    A    195.234.42.1
ns0.dddddd.eu.        3600    IN    A    11.111.111.111
ns1.xname.org.        600    IN    A    87.98.164.164

;; Query time: 53 msec
;; SERVER: 195.234.42.1#53(195.234.42.1)
;; WHEN: Sat Aug 21 22:43:46 2010
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 176
#########################################################################################
```

**my named.conf:**

```
include "/etc/namedb/rndc.key";
managed-keys {
    "." initial-key 257 3 8 "
    AwEAAagAIKlVZrpC6Ia7gEzahOR+9W29euxhJhVVLOyQ
    bSEW0O8gcCjFFVQUTf6v58fLjwBd0YI0EzrAcQqBGCzh
    /RStIoO8g0NfnfL2MTJRkxoXbfDaUeVPQuYEhg37NZWA
    JQ9VnMVDxP/VHL496M/QZxkjf5/Efucp2gaDX6RS6CXp
    oY68LsvPVjR0ZSwzz1apAzvN9dlzEheX7ICJBBtuA6G3
    LQpzW5hOA2hzCTMjJPJ8LbqF6dsV6DoBQzgul0sGIcGO
    Yl7OyQdXfZ57relSQageu+ipAdTTJ25AsRTAoub8ONGc
    LmqrAmRLKBP1dfwhYB4N7knNnulqQxA+Uk1ihz0= ";
    };

options {
   directory   "/etc/namedb/working";
   pid-file   "/var/run/named/pid";
   dump-file   "/var/dump/named_dump.db";
   statistics-file   "/var/stats/named.stats";
   allow-query { any; };
   dnssec-lookaside   auto;

   listen-on   { any; };

   disable-empty-zone "255.255.255.255.IN-ADDR.ARPA";
   disable-empty-zone "0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.IP6.ARPA";
   disable-empty-zone "1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.IP6.ARPA";

   forwarders {
      127.0.0.1;
   };
};
zone "." { type hint; file "/etc/namedb/named.root"; };

zone "dddddd.eu" {
   type master;
   file "/etc/namedb/master/dddddd.eu";
   allow-transfer { 92.243.14.172; 87.98.164.164; 195.234.42.1; 88.191.64.64; 89.252.22.138; 8.8.8.8; 8.8.4.4; localhost; 127.0.0.1; };
        allow-query { any; };
        };
```

**File dddddd.eu:**

```
$TTL   3600
@   IN   SOA   ns0.dddddd.eu. ns0.xname.org. (
      1;   Serial
      604800;   Refresh
      86400;   Retry
      2419200;   Expire
      86400 )   ;   Negative Cache TTL
;
dddddd.eu.   IN   NS   ns0.xname.org.
dddddd.eu.   IN   NS   ns1.xname.org.
dddddd.eu.   IN   NS   ns2.xname.org.
@   IN   NS   ns0.dddddd.eu.
@   IN   MX   10   mail.dddddd.eu.
@   IN   MX   20   mail2.dddddd.eu.
;
ns0   IN   A   11.111.111.111
mail2   IN   A   22.222.222.222
mail   IN   A   11.111.111.111
;
```

Comment: Please provide the conf file from the slave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your zone serial number `1` looks suspicious. You should update it every time when zone file changed or secondary server will not update. It is recommended to use something like 2010082201 for serial number.

Answer (score 0):

xname is historically known to be extremely slow to synchronize DNS data from your master.

If you look for something with quick sync, [BuddyNS](http://www.buddyns.com) auto-syncs in 10 minutes, or immediately if your master supports NOTIFY. That's secondary-only, so you need indeed your primary DNS to use it.